# Integrate google sign-in with vite app in local environment

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, oauth, vite

Javascript to handle stuff

```
 function onSignIn(googleUser) {
 console.log("sign in");
 // This function handles the successful sign-in.
 var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
 console.log("ID: " + profile.getId());
 console.log("Full Name: " + profile.getName());
 console.log("Given Name: " + profile.getGivenName());
 console.log("Family Name: " + profile.getFamilyName());
 console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
 console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());
 }

function onFailure(error) {
// This function handles sign-in failures.
console.log(error);
}

 
window.gapi.load("auth2", function () {
window.gapi.auth2.init({
client_id: cliendId,
});
});
```

html

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-floating mx-1" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"
            data-onfailure="onFailure">
            <i class="bi bi-google h4"></i>
          </button>
```

script

```
  <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

[The javascript origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF29n.png)

When i click the button nothing happens i have seen many similar type of questions but did not receive any desired results